# Azure Connection String with Spring profile

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-keyvault

I am new to Azure Spring Boot, I have done working simple POC with using spring boot and azure with using connection-string in environment property.( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-java-spring-app )

But I have the following requirements:

1) No need to set connection-string in environment property, in this case directly I want those connection-string bootstrap.yaml file.
Ex:(It is not working)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: azurespringappconfig
  cloud:
    azure:
      appconfiguration:
        stores:
          - connection-string: 'Endpoint=https://azurespringconfig:azconfig:xxxxxxxxxxx'
  #  cloud:
  #    azure:
  #      appconfiguration:
  #        stores:
  #          - connection-string: ${CONNECTIONSTRING}  -- this is working using environment
```

2) I need to apply profile concept: Here different profiles have different connection-string, so which profile active so going pick up the that connection-string.

Is any possibility to solve both the problems.

Thanks,
Amar